# What is the difference between MOD and REMAINDER in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Although both the functions perform the same operation, even they produce same o/p, what is basic difference between these two? Is there any performance related difference, if yes, then which one is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/remainder.php) is pretty clear on the difference:

> NOTE
>
> The REMAINDER function uses the round function in its formula, whereas
>   the MOD function uses the floor function in its formula.

In other words, when the arguments are positive integers, the mod function returns a positive number between 0 and the second argument.  The remainder function returns a number whose absolute value is less than the second argument divided by 2.

The differences can be more striking for negative numbers.  One example of a difference is:

```
REMAINDER(-15, 4)
MOD(-15, 4)
```

The first gives `-3` and the second `1`.

EDIT:

What is happening here?  How many times does 4 go into -15.  One method is "-4" times with a remained of 1.  That is:  -15 = 4*(-4) + 1.  The other is "-3" times:  -15 = 4*(-3) - 3.

The difference what is -15/4 expressed as an integer.  Using floor, you get `-4`.  Using round, you get `-3`.

Comment: it's not true that there's no difference in the case of positive integers: example: mod(49, 18) = 13 (Because 18*2=36+13 = 49 ) and remainder(49, 18) = -5 (Because 18*3 = 54 - 5 = 49)

Answer (score 8):

The difference between MOD and REMAINDER function can be understood in the example below:

MOD(13,5): returns 3 whereas, REMAINDER (13,5) returns -2

A simple way to understand the difference is that MOD uses the floor function therefore it counts the occurrence of the second number within the first and returns what is left to complete the first number i.e. 2(5) gives 10 adding 3 gives 13 therefore MOD(13,5)=3

However, the REMAINDER uses a Round function it therefore gets the total number of the second number that could make up the first and then subtract the what makes it excess. i.e. 3(5) = 15 and subtracting 2 gives 13,therefore REMAINDER(13,5)= -2

REMAINDER (-15, 4): 4(-4) gives -16 and adding +1 gives -15 hence REMAINDER (-15,4)=+1

MOD (-15, 4): 3(-4) gives -12, adding -3 gives us -15 hence MOD(15,4)=-3

Answer (score 2):

REMAINDER(-15, 4)--uses round without taking the sign of the number into 
                   consideration.

hence -15/4= -3.75==> round(-3.75)= -4.--(ignore sign during round)

```
         -4*4= -16
         -15-(-16)=>1
```

There fore:  REMAINDER(-15, 4)=1

MOD(-15, 4)----uses Floor without taking the sign of the number into 
               consideration.

```
         -15/4= -3.75==> floor(-3.75)= -3.--(ignore sign in floor)
          -3*4=-12
          -15-(-12)=>-3
```

There fore: MOD(-15, 4)= -3

Answer (score 2):

---

**Mod(m,n) is so simple to understand.**

---

**Finding Value** Mod() output value will always be the manually calculated remainder value when we divide m by n.

**Finding Sign** The sign of the output remains the same as the first parameter.

eg :

- **eg 1 : mod (11,3)** is the remainder of 11/3 which is **2** and the same sign of 1st parameter. So output is **2**
- **eg 2 : mod (-11,3)** is the remainder of 11/3 which is **2** and the same sign of the 1st parameter. So the output is **-2**

---

**Remainder(m,n)  is a bit different**

---

**Finding Value** You take two multiples of n, such that when multiplied gives the closest lower value and the closest upper value compared to the first parameter(m). The minimum difference between these values will be the output value

**Finding Sign** The sign of the output value will always be positive if the closest value is less than the first parameter and the if the closest value is greater than the 1st parameter then it will be negative.

eg :

- **eg 1 : remainder(10,3)** The closest multiple values of 3 which are lesser and greater than 10 are 9(3x3) and 12(3x4). And the closest to 10 among 9 & 12 is 9. So the output will be the gap between 9 and 10 which is **1**. The closest number is less than the 1st parameter. So the output is **1**.
- **eg 2 : remainder(11,3)** The closest multiple values of 11 which are lesser and greater than 11 are 9(3x3) and 12(3x4). And the closest to 12 among 9 & 12 is 12. So the output will be the gap between 12 and 11 which is **1**. The closest number is greater than the 1st parameter. So the output is **-1**.

Answer (score 1):

The question has long had an answer, but I thought some context would be helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation discusses the “modulo” operation, and the fact that it is based on the remainder after integer division. The problem is that the concept of “remainder” is not clearly defined where there are negative numbers.

Where negative numbers are involved, the difference between modulus and remainder is significant. Mathematically, the modulus operation maps an integer on to a range. This range begins at 0 and is cyclic. For example `integer mod 3` is mapped on to the range:

```
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, …
```

If the given integer is negative, the cycle is simply extended backwards. If, however, the modulus itself is negative, then the whole range is negative:

```
0, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, …
```

https://rob.conery.io/2018/08/21/mod-and-remainder-are-not-the-same/ illustrates this as a clock with negative numbers.

The practical upshot of this is that the sign of the second number is the same as the sign of the result.

With a remainder, however, you attempt to divide the second number into the first number until you can’t go any more. The remaining difference is called the remainder. If the first number is negative, then, if you stop short, the remainder will be negative.

The practical upshot of which is that the sign of the first number is the sign of the result.

Most coding languages, including most variations of SQL, use a remainder calculation, but very often call it the modulus. And most languages use the notation `a % b` meaning `a mod b`.

Oracle, of course, has two functions, which should have been helpful. However, the first function, `mod()`, actually gives what everybody else calls the remainder. The second, `remainder()`  gives a result which nobody else gives, due to the fact that it is focused on the *nearest* division. As per the documentation, the `mod()` functions uses the `floor()` function, while `remainder()` uses `round()`.

If you want to compare the results, you can try:

```sql
SELECT
    remainder(19,5) AS "Remainder ++",
    remainder(-19,5) AS "Remainder -+",
    remainder(19,-5) AS "Remainder +-",
    remainder(-19,-5) AS "Remainder --",
    mod(19,5) AS "Mod ++",
    mod(-19,5) AS "Mod -+",
    mod(19,-5) AS "Mod +-",
    mod(-19,-5) AS "Mod --",
    mod(mod(19,5) + 5,5) AS "Modulo ++",
    mod(mod(-19,5) + 5,5) AS "Modulo ++",
    mod(mod(19,-5) + -5,-5) AS "Modulo ++",
    mod(mod(-19,-5) + -5,-5) AS "Modulo ++"
FROM DUAL
;
```

The `modulo` calculation gives the true modulus, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

In all, you probably want the **remainder** as the most natural interpretation, and so you will use `mod()` to get this result.