# remainder function in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Not able to getting the remainder() function in oracle. Below are two examples with output. Just let me know the logic behind this with these examples for my better understanding.

```
select remainder(17,3) from dual; // output -1
select remainder(15,6) from dual; // output 3
```

In particular, why does `remainder(15,6)` not return `-3` since round(15 / 6) = 3?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions133.htm - Why not read this

Comment: RTFM - Please just read the manual page

Comment: I think you maybe confusing remainder with `MOD`.  Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449229/what-is-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder-in-oracle

Comment: Even reading contents from above links, the logic is not sync with my above examples.  so, anyone knows and willing to explain with above examples kindly do post.

Comment: Good question, although the wording is a bit vague. FWIW it took more than just reading the documentation to understand what's going on here, since the documentation misleadingly suggests that `remainder` uses `round`, whereas it actually has its own idea of how rounding should be done.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - Are you saying the Oracle's documentation is misleading and hard to follow. Now that is a revelation!

Answer (score 1):

REMAINDER is a rather odd SQL function, I've never used it myself.

```
17 / 3 = 5.66666..
which rounds to 6
17 / 3 = 6 remainder -1

15 / 6 = 2.5
which is rounded to 2 (note: this is NOT using Oracle's default ROUND algorithm!)
15 / 6 = 2 remainder 3
```

[Understanding behavior of remainder() function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625194/understanding-behavior-of-remainder-function-in-oracle)

EDIT

As per Jonathan's comment, it appears the binary_float/binary_double logic for `round` is being used, which rounds to the nearest even value.

```
select  9 / 6, remainder(9,6)
      ,15 / 6, remainder(15,6)
      ,21 / 6, remainder(21,6)
      ,27 / 6, remainder(27,6)
from dual;

1.5 -3
2.5  3
3.5 -3
4.5  3
```

Comment: The [ROUND()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) page says: _For NUMBER values, the value n is rounded away from 0 (for example, to x+1 when x.5 is positive and to x-1 when x.5 is negative). For BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE values, the function rounds to the nearest even value._  Maybe the intermediate result of (15 / 6) is being treated as BINARY_DOUBLE rather than NUMBER?  It would at least account for the observed behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think you're on to something there. `remainder(21,6) = -3` and `remainder(27,6) = 3`